# Python: Searching for date using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for date information, in the format of 01-JAN-2023 in a extracted text, and the following regular expression didn't work.  Can \b and \Y be used this way?

```
import re

rext = 'This is the testing text with 01-Jan-2023'

match = re.search(r"\d\b\Y", rext)
print(match)
```

Comment: They're not regex directives, so no. `\d` is a digit, `\b` is a word boundary and `\Y` doesn't mean anything - https://regex101.com/r/bkKh6t/1.

Comment: r"\d+-\w+-\d+" 
You didn't think hyphen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import re

rext = 'This is the testing text with 01-Jan-2023'

match = re.search(r"\d+-\w+-\d+", rext)
print(match)
```

```
<re.Match object; span=(30, 41), match='01-Jan-2023'>
```

Comment: Thank you!  In the case when there's a "/" at the end, 01-Jan-2023/, what would I need to add to recognise "01-Jan-2023/"?

Comment: ```\``` is a special character so you have to neutralize it by adding \ before ie ```\\``` but like ```/``` is not special you could let it as well

Comment: ```rext = 'This is the testing text with 1-Jan-23/ ' ``` with 
 ```match = re.search(r"\d+-\w+-\d+/", rext) ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regular expression:

```py
match = re.search(r"\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}", rext)
print(match.group())
```

`\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`).

`[a-zA-Z]` matches an upper- or lower-case letter.

`{n}` matches the preceding pattern n times.

Comment: won't work with '1-Jan-23'

Comment: @LaurentB. The input specifically has "**01**-Jan".

Comment: Rigth but it's more secure to generalize in case of format change in the run